# AFNetworking Clang Error with Exit code 254 - Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: afnetworking

I am trying to use AFNetworking with Xcode 4.6.2 in my projects. I have added the AFNetworking to my project. I have also added 'SystemConfiguration' and 'MobileCoreServices' framework to the project. I have included the framework header files in the .pch file like below

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

When I try to run the project, I get Clang error from file AFHTTPClient as follows

```
    Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok , I solved the problem. The issue was with order of import statements in .pch file

I changed the order to as follows basically added 'AFNetworking.h' after import statements for  and  frameworks.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

Also another tip. You also need to add 'Security' framework for AFNetworking to work smoothly. Thanks